# Akka finite state machine instances

Tags: java, scala, akka, state-machine

I am trying to leverage Akka's finite state machine framework for my use case. I am working on a system that processes a request that goes through various states.

The request here is the application name that needs to be deployed along with the application it depends on:

```
Request for application A -> A is in a QUEUED state
Discover A's dependency B -> B is in a QUEUED state
B is being processed -> B is in a PROCESSING STATE
A is being processed -> A is in a PROCESSING STATE
B is processed -> B is in a DONE state
A is processed -> A is in a DONE state
```

For this I am initializing a finite state machine at discovery time. So `A`'s FSM is created when the request comes in, `B`'s FSM is initialized when `B` is discovered from one of the actors.

Do I initialize and pass the FSM instance to all the actors, and at the same time `tell` the FSM about the operations being performed on the data so that the state machine goes in the correct state?

Here is the relevant portion of the state machine:

```
when(QUEUED, matchEvent(requestAccepted.class, MyApp.class,
    (requestAccepted, service) -> 
    goTo(PROCESSING).replying(PROCESSING)));

when(PROCESSING, matchEvent(completed.class, MyApp.class,
    (completed, service) -> goTo(DONE).replying(DONE)));

// During transitions, save states in the database.
onTransition(matchState(PROCESSING, DONE, () -> {
  nextStateData().setServiceStatus(DONE);
  databaseWriter.tell(nextStateData(), getSelf());
```

And here is an example from one of the actors processing the request:

```
ProcessingActor extends AbstractActor {

    @Override
      public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {
        if (message instanceof processApplication) {
         // process the app
         // Initialize FSM for the Application
         FSM myFSM = Props.create(MYFSM.class);
         myFSM.tell( new completed(processApplication.app)
    }
```

Is this the right way to initialize the state machine and use it? Or should the initialization happen in the constructor of the `ProcessingActor`? But in that case there wouldn't be one state machine per application (data).

Comment: I think this question misses answers because it is very unclear. I re-read it 3 times and still not sure what you are trying to achieve and how. I think this is made worse by the fact that you seem to use term "application" in at least two different meanings or else I totally don't get what your sentence "_I am working on an **application** that processes the **application** ..._"  means. Please, try to add more details to the question and then someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable in its current state. It is too opinion based and vague. If you solution works, then it works. Who is to say what is "the right way".

Comment: it works now, but I want to know if this design would sustain.

Comment: in general AKKA solutions are not write once. the APIs tend to change over time expect to need to rewrite it for a new akka version. 
if you use akka 2.5.x you should be using receivebuilders. instead of onReceive.

Comment: There are classes more specialized in FSM, like `AbstractFSMWithStash` you can use them instead of the general `AbstractActor`

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; While the description of states and transitions is rather ambiguous in the OP, the status of the chosen implementation, its implications and those of alternatives can be addressed.

The implementation at hand can count as an "actor per request" approach, as opposed to what more frequently can be found, where the state-machine actor buffers and handles multiple requests. It will be presented further below.

In its present form the given implementation is the only *AbstractFSM per request* I know of, actually with yet another FSM downstream, which then can't be called "per request" any more and likely could be avoided. It looks roughly like this:

[image: actor per request FSM]

The "actor per request" initially seems to have come up in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spray-user/5x9kba7j1FI/r_aaDTPWHFkJ), which gave raise to [this blog](http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/) and a bit later even occasionally claimed the title of [a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577043/akka-http-actor-per-request-pattern). It seems in part it was motivated by replicating one of the features of the [Spray framework](http://spray.io/), sort of precursor of Akka http.

Another discussion on SO came to an [inconclusive result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113468/akka-how-many-instances-of-an-actor-should-you-create?rq=1) on the question whether to prefer a single actor over one per request, and presents [routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/routing.html) as a 3rd alternative, because a router also acts as a load balancer, touching the [back-pressure](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#54-should-do-back-pressure) topic.

The approach more frequently presented in combination with `AbstractFSM` and its varieties, though, is a single FSM actor that buffers
incoming messages utilizing the `whenUnhandled` method to accumulate them by default, no matter what the current state is (e.g. Akka in Action, chapter ["Finite State Machines and Agents"](https://livebook.manning.com/book/akka-in-action/chapter-11/60) or the Lightbend [buncher example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/fsm.html?language=java)). I'm not able to back up the claim with a reference, but it looks like *AbstractFSM is more thought of to model the states of an actor that deals with multiple requests, rather than that of a request that goes through multiple stages*.
Related to the OP that approach would mean, that `ProcessingActor`
itself could extend `AbstractFSM`.

```
public class ProcessingActor extends AbstractFSM<sample.so.State, RequestQueue> {
{
    startWith(Idle, new RequestQueue());

    when(Idle, /* matchEvent(EventType, DataType, Action) */
            matchEvent(
                    Request.class,
                    RequestQueue.class,
                    (request, queue) -> goTo(Processing).using(queue.push(request)));
    /* more state-matchers */

    whenUnhandled(
            matchEvent(
                    Request.class,
                    RequestQueue.class,
                    (request, qeue) -> stay().using(qeue.push(request)));

    initialize();
}
```

Arriving at something like this for the "request"-part, where the database writes aren't represented by states any more, rather than state entry and exit actions. Note that all the `whenUnhandled` branch doesn't appear in the diagram, since it isn't related to a state change.

[image: single actor FSM]

Without going too much into weighing (vague) requirements against the chosen implementation, `AbstractFSM` seems to be a rather clumsy machinery to log a sequence of status per request to a database. The documentation of the 2.4 version of Akka presents a state machine [without](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/fsm.html) using AbstractFsm and discusses the possibility to distinguish first events and then states or the other way round. In the `AbstractFSM`-DSL you're bound to discern states before events (and data). It can even be argued with some justification to abstain from the akka FSM [altogether](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#55-should-not-use-akka-fsm).

A more light-weight approach to build FSM utilizes [become/unbecome](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html?language=scala#Become_Unbecome), a nice presentation is [here](https://petabridge.com/blog/akka-actors-finite-state-machines-switchable-behavior/), an `AbstractFSM` vs. become/unbecome discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110045/fsm-vs-become-unbecome-in-akka). Closer visual proximity to business rules gives the major argument for the former.

Entering the more slippery terrain of judging the use of AbstractFSM for the task at had. I think, some things can be said, given the reading of the requirements is approximately ok.

The states form a linear chain, so the two "AbstractFSM-per-request" can be replaced by other per-request structures:

- a single chain of actors, each of them representing one state

[image: chain of actors]

- a single actor, sending events to itself, one event type per step shown above, emitting messages to the database writer at each point. Perhaps an enumeration would suffice as well.

The appeal of those versions may increase considering this: since the given implementation uses (at least) one FSM per request, the question arises, how the transition `QUEUED->PROCESSING` comes about (or `discovery processing -> discovery done` for that matter), and what `QUEUED` relates to a technical level. Items are never in a queue, always in an exclusive actor (on the other hand a QUEUED state would be more obvious in a [single-FSM](https://livebook.manning.com/book/akka-in-action/chapter-11/60) approach which actually uses a queue, but then **the state doesn't apply to the actor, but to the item the actor handles**). It is not obvious, which [external event](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#51-should-evolve-the-state-of-actors-only-in-response-to-messages-received-from-the-outside) should cause that transition. Akka FSM is geared to describe deterministic [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (see also [this](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#55-should-not-use-akka-fsm), giving the same argument for the opposite reasons), but if this transition is not triggered by an external event, the FSM must become [nondeterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) and trigger its own [epsilon-transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#NFA_with_%CE%B5-moves) ~ transitions not caused by any input. A rather complicated structure, probably implemented somehow like this:

```
onTransition(
    matchState(Initial, Queued, () -> {                    
        getSelf().tell(new Epsilon(), getSelf());
    }));
```